# Connect to Exchange Server using Autodiscover in Java

Tags: java, exchange-server

We are trying to connect to our exchange server using an autodiscover url. The url is returning a wsdl file when running using a REST client:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("truststore.jks"), null);
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
client = Client.create(config);
config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, ctx));
webResource = client.resource("https://autodiscover.company.com/xxxx/autodiscover.svc");
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
```

But it is returning 401 unauthorized error when running using exchange service:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("truststore.jks"),null);
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.setTraceEnabled(true);
service.setPreAuthenticate(true);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username,password,domain);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUserAgent(user);
service.setUrl(new java.net.URI("https://autodiscover.company.com/xxxx/autodiscover.svc"));
```

Following is the stack trace:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpErrorException: The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorize
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:729)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:36)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:140)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:945)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:998)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:1070)
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ews-java-api jar version to 2.0 and that did the trick :-)